# How to write and execute a script that will create directories and .txt files

Tags: linux

I am attempting to create text files in folders. When running my code (`Create_txt_files`) in Linux shell, all I am getting are the following errors:

```
e@01:/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/study_scripts/eric_scripts$ . Create_txt_files**

bash: /mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data: **Is a directory**

bash: /mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL: **No such file or directory**

bash: /mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL/session1: **No such file or directory**
```

There are about 9 more lines of this same error code. I understand that there is "no such file or directory" in the lines after the first error code, but that's because these directories are not being created. My code is as follows, which is designed to write the necessary folders:

```
# Location of Subject
/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data mkdir emsintTESTFSL

# Make session1 & session2 folders
/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL mkdir session1 session2

# Make control, exper1, & exper2 folders
/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL/session1 mkdir control exper1 exper2

# Create CONTROL files
/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL/session1/control mkdir run1 run2
/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL/session1/control/run1
/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL/session1/control/run1 touch correct.txt
/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL/session1/control/run1 touch incorrect.txt
/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL/session1/control/run1 touch missing.txt

/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL/session1/control/run2
/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL/session1/control/run2 touch correct.txt
/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL/session1/control/run2 touch incorrect.txt
/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL/session1/control/run2 touch missing.txt
```

I believe I am executing my code incorrectly in linux shell. I am executing it by typing ". Create_txt_files" in its designated Path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to either 'cd' to the directory first or include it in the 'mkdir' command. The same with 'touch'

```
cd /mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data 
mkdir emsintTESTFSL

or

mkdir /mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsintTESTFSL
```